# Content security policy error : violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' 'self' https://localhost:44321

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

I have a web application in which I have added a ContentSecurityPolicy middleware configured like this

```
  options[CspDirective.FormAction].ApprovedSources.Add("'self'");
  options[CspDirective.FormAction].ApprovedSources.Add("https://localhost:44321");
  options[CspDirective.FormAction].ApprovedSources.Add("https://*.test.com");
  options[CspDirective.FormAction].ApprovedSources.Add("https://*.testdev.com");
```

I have a JavaScript file which has the content as,

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("callbackForm").submit();
}
```

and the html

```
<form id="callbackForm" method="POST" action="@ViewBag.CallbackUrl">
```

but when I run the application it says because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self' 'self' https://localhost:44321 `https://*.test.com https://*.testdev.com".`

Comment: What is the current URL, and what is `@ViewBag.CallbackUrl`?

Comment: i was able to fix it

Comment: May I ask how was it fixed?